# Regression code

Tags: r

How do I create a customized function in R that fits all multiple linear regression models from the given data with number of variables specified by the user? The function looks like this:

```
BodyFat.lm <- lm(PercentBodyFat ~ ., data = BodyFat)
```

fits for all data. I want function where user specify the number of variables like

```
(my.data = BodyFat, n = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want with [dredge](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/MuMIn/docs/dredge) in the [MuMin package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/index.html). Perhaps something like this:

```
library(MuMIn)
BodyFat.lm.2 <- dredge(BodyFat.lm, m.max=2, m.min=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a great resource which shows a possible solution, you might want to reference the following excellent post by Mark Heckmann which [shows how to calculate all possible linear regression models for a given set of predictors](http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/r-calculating-all-possible-linear-regression-models-for-a-given-set-of-predictors/). As the author points out, you can take a few approaches:

1) Write a lot of code (he does this), to follow a repetition driven step-by-step analysis approach

2) Make use of a specialized package. The author suggests the packages **leaps** and **meifly**, but notes that both seem to have some drawbacks. Note that you can see specific code and more information on Hadley Wickham's meifly package here: https://github.com/hadley/meifly/